# Convert Pandas date column from dd-mmm-yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe that stores date in the format `19-Jul-18`. I am trying to convert it to `2018-07-19`

I tried doing `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` but it dint help.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series('19-Jul-18'),format='%d-%b-%y')
`

Comment: @W-B thanks for the reply but wouldn't the above return the same output "19-Jul-18". I am trying to get a format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: It will return yyyy-mm-dd , did you try running above ?

Comment: @W-B yes I had tried this and it returned the same format (19-Jul-18) hence wanted to ask you .

Comment: Just `dt = pd.to_datetime(['19-Jul-18'])` works.

Comment: You are not assign it back s=pd.to_datetime(pd.Series('19-Jul-18'),format='%d-%b-%y')

Comment: @coldspeed tried your suggestion as well and it returns the same output. Column type is "datetime64[ns]"

Comment: @W-B, I did try assigning it back to a new column as well

Comment: Either you didn't try it, or you did it wrong. I would be nice _what_ you're trying to do in your code. Maybe a screenshot, or copy-paste the cells with their output.

Comment: If you need to change String   import time
today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
today

Comment: @coldspeed thanks it worked, had to clean the kernel and re-try and that worked.. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @W-B thanks that helped.